# GEO location query PHP and SQL with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently working on a campaign/advertisement script in Laravel 5.2. I'm having a table with ads, for example: Ad name, Location (lat/long), Radius (+10km).

Now I have a user location (lat/long). I want to see if he is in the radius of any ad and show the ad to him.

I have this:

```
public function scopeAdsInLocation($query, $from_latitude, $from_longitude)
{
    $query = CampaignModel::
    where(\DB::raw('111.1111 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(' . $from_latitude . ')) * COS(RADIANS(campaigns.loc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(' . $from_longitude .' -
        campaigns.loc_long)) + SIN(RADIANS(' . $from_latitude . ')) * SIN(RADIANS(campaigns.loc_lat))))'), '<=', 'campaigns.loc_radius')
        ->get();
    return $query;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
$ads = CampaignModel::adsInLocation(51.191320, 5.987772);
var_dump($ads);
```

This code works, but only if I set the radius to a fixed value. So when I replace campaigns.loc_radius with '100' it works. But with the radius each campaign has it doesn't seem to do the job. Do you know maybe why? Or have a solution for this.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to do the job" <- Can you be more specific?

Comment: "It doesn't work" or "It doesn't seem to do the job" is completely meaningless. What constitutes "doing the job"? What is it doing now that isn't "doing the job"?

Comment: do you want `10` or `100` ?? what is the value for `campaigns.loc_radius`?? Because you say want `10km` but replace it with `100`

Comment: I mean each ad has a radius from a lot/long it needs to be showed to a user who is in the radius of that ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `where()`, you can use

```
\DB::raw("`campaigns`.`loc_radius`")
```

So your query will be as:

```
public function scopeAdsInLocation($query, $from_latitude, $from_longitude)
{
    $query = CampaignModel::
    where(\DB::raw('111.1111 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(' . $from_latitude . ')) * COS(RADIANS(campaigns.loc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(' . $from_longitude .' -
        campaigns.loc_long)) + SIN(RADIANS(' . $from_latitude . ')) * SIN(RADIANS(campaigns.loc_lat))))'), '<=', \DB::raw("`campaigns`.`loc_radius`"))
        ->get();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Really thanks, as far as I see and test this does the job :).
For any other user who wants to know how this works.

I have a table with ads/campaigns each campaign has a lat/long and a radius. (for example paris +100km) If a user has entered the radius of this ad so he is near paris or in the 100km radius he sees the ad. Otherwise he sees nothing. But each ad has own lat/long. But it works now :) Feel free to use this code.